# Fill Pdf with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, pdf

I have created a PDF form that represents a certificate. Is there any way to fill out the form automatically from a SQL db or some other source and create each filled form with a different mailing address?

If there isn't a way, can someone point out how could I make it using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use iText for monkeying with PDFs in c#.

http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8